# how to remove extra spacing on top of my section

Tags: html, css

I tried making 2 sections one next to the other, I managed, but after adding things to my first section a unknown spacing appeared on top of it so the sections can't be linear at all.

I've already tried various things such ass changing the width, removing padding and margin, removing the container, and other common things but nothing seems to work, so I'd like you to help me how to fix this problem and explain why this problem apperes if possible.

```css
    .chip-area {
        border-bottom: darkred 10px solid;
        background-color: #efefef;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .chip-select-area {
        height: 380px;
        width: 40%;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .stage-select-area {
        height: 380px;
        width: 50%;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .img-chip-area {
        height: 100%;
    }

    .chip-area-s {
        width: 70%;
        margin-left: 10px;
    }

    .s-container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 25%;
    }
```

```html
  <section class="chip-area">
        <div class="container">
            <section class="chip-select-area">
                <div class="s-container">
                 <img class="img-chip-area" src="img.png">
                 <select class="chip-area-s"></select>
                </div>
                <div class="s-container">
                 <img class="img-chip-area" src="img.png">
                 <select class="chip-area-s"></select>
                </div>
             <div class="s-container">
                 <img class="img-chip-area" src="img.png">
                 <select class="chip-area-s"></select>
              </div>
              <div class="s-container">
                  <img class="img-chip-area" src="img.png">
                  <select class="chip-area-s"></select>
              </div>
            </section>
            <section class="stage-select-area">    
            </section>
        </div>
    </section>
```

here is an image of the extra space http://prntscr.com/nr90sy

Comment: i don't see an image

Comment: forgot to place the [link](http://prntscr.com/nr90sy) (added now)

Comment: i cannot see any extra space in code snippet. please check again

Comment: You can see the extra spacing in the snippet if you look it in a full page Xenio Gracias

Comment: The problem is how your sections are positioned next to each other. I would recommend you take a look at flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because of `inline-block`. You need to set `vertical-align: top` to your elements.

See below

```css
.chip-area {
        border-bottom: darkred 10px solid;
        background-color: #efefef;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .chip-select-area {
        height: 380px;
        width: 40%;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
    }
    .stage-select-area {
        height: 380px;
        width: 50%;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .img-chip-area {
        height: 100%;
    }

    .chip-area-s {
        width: 70%;
        margin-left: 10px;
    }

    .s-container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 25%;
    }
```

```html
<section class="chip-area">
        <div class="container">
            <section class="chip-select-area">
                <div class="s-container">
                 <img class="img-chip-area" src="img.png">
                 <select class="chip-area-s"></select>
                </div>
                <div class="s-container">
                 <img class="img-chip-area" src="img.png">
                 <select class="chip-area-s"></select>
                </div>
             <div class="s-container">
                 <img class="img-chip-area" src="img.png">
                 <select class="chip-area-s"></select>
              </div>
              <div class="s-container">
                  <img class="img-chip-area" src="img.png">
                  <select class="chip-area-s"></select>
              </div>
            </section>
            <section class="stage-select-area">    
            </section>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

`display: inline-block;` **to change** `display:block;`  **from** `.chip-select-area` **class**

```css
    .chip-area {
        border-bottom: darkred 10px solid;
        background-color: #efefef;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .chip-select-area {
        height: 380px;
        width: 40%;
        display:block;
    }
    .stage-select-area {
        height: 380px;
        width: 50%;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .img-chip-area {
        height: 100%;
    }

    .chip-area-s {
        width: 70%;
        margin-left: 10px;
    }

    .s-container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 25%;
    }
```

```html
  <section class="chip-area">
        <div class="container">
            <section class="chip-select-area">
                <div class="s-container">
                 <img class="img-chip-area" src="img.png">
                 <select class="chip-area-s"></select>
                </div>
                <div class="s-container">
                 <img class="img-chip-area" src="img.png">
                 <select class="chip-area-s"></select>
                </div>
             <div class="s-container">
                 <img class="img-chip-area" src="img.png">
                 <select class="chip-area-s"></select>
              </div>
              <div class="s-container">
                  <img class="img-chip-area" src="img.png">
                  <select class="chip-area-s"></select>
              </div>
            </section>
            <section class="stage-select-area">    
            </section>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score -2):

Just reset its property before you do something

`body,html{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}`